# Re-declaration of property with different type causes binding problems

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

In C# there is a possibility to re-declare property in derived class with different type. From what I've tried it works, but in case we use binding, we will get *BindingException* - program expects type of base class not a derived one. A sample can look like this - XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="24"/>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get { return 8.ToString(); } }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new int Name { get { return 6; } }
}

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DerivedClass myClass = new DerivedClass();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Name = {myClass.Name}");
    DataContext = myClass;
}
```

If we run this, we will see that `Name = 6` but we will get binding exception (expects string and gets int).

Is it a desired behavior that XAML binding expects type of base class memebers?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't say it's a good pattern (definitely not), also that one should use that. I only ask if it's a designed behavior. There are no warnings at all (at least with standard options).

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think I've found the answer - thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

As [Henk Holterman posted in comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb613546(v=vs.100).aspx) *DataBinding* uses reflection to get property names - some more info you can find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding). In case we hide property in derived class with new type, the reflection returns two types.

```
PropertyInfo[] info = myClass.GetType().GetProperties().ToArray();
```

From what I've tried it seems that when there is more than one type among properties with the same name, the *BindingExpression* will throw exception.